# Am I okay to use a client-provided laptop and work phone with IR35?

Tags: contracts, legal

I'm using a client-provided laptop to carry out work on a day-to-day basis. However, another contractor is using a personal one for IR35 reasons (ie, using his own demonstrates that he's not an employee). He's also refused a work phone to keep his business and the client separated.

We deal with a lot of sensitive and personal financial information so I figured it'd be best to use the client laptop for security reasons.

So, am I okay to use a client-provided laptop and work phone or does it contradict IR35? I've searched online for an answer but can't find a solid 'yes' or 'no'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer, nor am I innately familiar with IR35 and UK contract law)*

[Kate Cottrell](http://www.contractoruk.com/ir35/contractors_questions_does_using_client_kit_affect_4793.html) had this to say on the matter:

> ...providing your own kit is a pointer away from IR35 but if you are unable to make such a provision then it becomes a neutral point.

[Lesley Furber](http://www.crunch.co.uk/contractor-advice/2011/07/22/how-to-make-your-contracts-ir35-proof/) also mentions in an article:

> Freelancers and Contractors often find that they are required to use the client’s equipment, possibly for safety and security reasons. This is generally not an issue that would make a contract fail IR35 if there is a sound business reason for it.

Based on these, I'd say that your use of client-provided equipment (laptop, phone), while not ideal, is still fine, given the fact that there is a great deal of sensitive information in play.